# Captive portal without changing router firmware

Tags: openwrt, captive-portal

I could find a way to create captive portal using OpenWrt in but I'm thinking a method of doing it without changing firmware, is it possible ?.if it what are the ways?

Comment: It is probably not unless your router has a built-in option for it. But you didn't even mention what router you have...

Comment: No;  There is no way to configure a captive portal using OpenWRT unless you actually replace the firmware with OpenWRT.  You certainly can use some other firmware that has a captive portal.

Comment: @Ramhound, his question was if he can do "captive portal" without replacing the firmware with something like OpenWRT.

Comment: @YisroelTech - That isn't what the question says.  They specifically asked about the captive portal functionality with regards to OpenWRT.

Comment: @Ramhound, I understood the question otherwise. He specifically asked that he wants to have a captive portal without changing firmware (which he would need to do to get the captive portal using OpenWRT.)

Comment: thank you for your valuable comments , I think I got the idea , which means I cannot build captive portal without changing firmware unless I have built-in functionalities  to do so.